# Windows command (copy) | parameters | allow destination file path to be created

Tags: windows, command-line, path

When using Window's command `copy`, i'm unable to find a way to force the *destination-path* to be created.

In the following example (assume that the source destination isn't created which is drive `D:/`

## EXAMPLE

`copy "D:\_steam\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg\autoexec.cfg" "D:\_material\Counter-Strike Global Offensive/autoexec.cfg"`

due to the fact that the destination-path isn't created (*error*):

`user@pc $ "D:\_steam\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg\autoexec.cfg" "D:\_material\Counter-Strike Global Offensive/autoexec.cfg"
The system cannot find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.`

## QUICK-FIX

Go ahead and manually create the destination path for the file to be copied over to. **But this isn't a viable solution**.

## FINAL THOUGHTS

I'm looking for a way (*only possibility, since it's a command, is a parameter*) that allows the destination-path to be created.

Hopefully it'll be possible to have this be done via 1-line of code

## REFERENCE

take a look at parameter `/D` here (doesn't work in my case):
http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way using "copy". You can use xcopy or construct a batch file that accepts source and destination, then tests for the destination, creates the destination if it doesn't exist, then copies the file.

Comment: I was hoping that this all could be done with just *1-line of code* rather than having to *construct a batch file*